# SE does not award Vox Populi badge, even if I use 40 votes per day

Tags: support, bug, badges

**This is regarding the Buddhism SE, not its Meta.**
This happened both today and yesterday. I am new to this site and I went through a lot of questions yesterday and today, and upvoted a lot. Because of that, yesterday I got the Suffrage badge for using 30 votes per day, but did not get the Vox Populi for using 40 per day, which I did yesterday. I tried the same thing today, but same result. When I viewed the progress of the badge both times after using 40 votes (I got the notification **Daily vote limit reached, vote again in x hours**), it showed 39 out of 40.

Is this a bug in this site only? Because I have tried this on other sites and I had no issues getting the Vox Populi there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is a frequently-asked question in the main Meta site --

https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=vox+populi+39

And perhaps it's related to something you voted on being deleted.

Comment: I tried this again today, and this time I was careful not to vote on answers from delete users. But my current daily vote count is shown as 31 out of 40 in the badges section, and when I click the Upvote button 2 more times, I get the warning saying "5 votes left", meaning SE thinks 33 (33+2+5=40) votes has been cast for today and not 31(31+2+5=38). Then I checked the list of votes in my profile, and it shows 31 entries. So I wonder, where those additional 2 votes are?

Comment: I'm unable to see how you voted, and have no previous experience with this phenomenon. You might get a better answer on the main meta.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: Okay thank you.